# Is there a "syntactic sugar" way to escapte XML attributes values without String.replace?

Tags: java, xml, escaping

From the XML specs...

> To allow attribute values to contain
>   both single and double quotes, the
>   apostrophe or single-quote character
>   (') may be represented as "`&apos;`",
>   and the double-quote character (") as
>   "`&quot;`".

Is there a standard or easier way to do it rather than using string find / replace? (apache commons?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jon Skeet. If you really have no choice, consider using [StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) from commons-lang.

Comment: I thought about it, but didn't realise it can help me escape individual attributes... looking at the API docs I guess it does... thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use an XML API instead of trying to do it all through string manipulation, to be honest.

There are so many little things you could easily get wrong - why not use a purpose-built API?

Comment: I agree, but which one? the Java Document builder is a living hell, we don't have the nice .NET XMLBuilders you have ;)

Comment: @Eran: There are plenty to choose from, and pretty much all of them are going to be better than doing string manipulation. It's been a while since I've done any XML work in Java, but JDOM isn't bad from what I remember.